# getting separate url of video and audio after parse the master playlist file

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services

I am getting separate url for audio and video after parse the master playlist so I am unable to play specific quality video with audio. Actually I wanted to implement manual bitrate control of video in player, for this purpose I parse the master playlist in order to get url of different bitrate video. I am getting the HLS file from Azure media service in which video is encoded with different bitrate.
Following shows that how my master playlist looks like:

[image]

specific quality video url only contains video fragment not audio. Suggest me how I can retrieve specific quality video with audio from Azure Media Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct - the current HLS specification requires that the tracks are not muxed together when used with fragmented MP4 segments or TS segments.

To get back a track with video and audio muxed together, you can request the very old version of the HLS spec which supported muxed audio and video TS segments. Just use the format=m3u8-aapl-v3 on the URL, and use the audioTrack to point to the specific audio track to mux if needed (optional)

/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audioTrack=audio_1)

The other workflow is to submit an "subclipping" encoding job and just get back a normal Mp4 file with the audio and video muxed back together.

Be aware though that the industry has mostly moved on to the latest HLS and DASH specs which specify that all tracks are un-muxed (seperate audio and video tracks.) Most streaming players support the latest un-muxed CMAF style streams from HLS and DASH.

Comment: thanks for your response and I finally got the solution after searching a lot.One more thing I want to ask you that in future the format:format=m3u8-aapl-v3 would be depreciated?or in future  would I not be able to get muxed audio and video together using format=m3u8-aapl-v3 ?

Comment: We will definitely keep support around for v3, that we can't easily deprecate as there are still a lot of legacy devices out there that support it.  But you should be aware that Apple's plan is to move over to CMAF completely - which would be unmuxed Mp4 fragments per RFC 8216https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8216#section-3.3